# Error creating user groups from text file

Tags: bash, suse

I have a problem with a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# El argumento tipo corresponde a usuario o grupo.
# El argumento accion corresponde a crear o eliminar cualquiera de los anteriores.
tipo=$1
accion=$2
if [ $tipo = "usuario" ]; then
    while IFS=, read -r nombre usuario grupo
    do
        if [ $accion = "crear" ]; then
            useradd "$usuario" -c "$nombre" -m -G "$grupo" 
        else
            sudo userdel "$usuario" -r -f
        fi
    done < /tmp/usuarios_fles.txt
    echo "----- Usuarios procesados ----"
    exit 0
else
    while IFS= read -r grupo
    do
        if [ $accion = "crear" ]; then
            groupadd "$grupo"
        else
            groupdel "$grupo" -f
        fi
    done < /tmp/grupos_fles.txt
    exit 0
    echo "----- Grupos procesados ----"
fi
```

The file:

```
/tmp/groups_fles.txt
```

it only contains these text strings:

```
adminuser
readwriteuser
readuser
```

It gives me the following error on Suse 11.3, I test on Fedora 33 and it doesn't show the error:

```
'.oupadd: Invalid group name `adminuser
'.oupadd: Invalid group name `readwriteuser
'.oupadd: Invalid group name `readuser
```

I don't know what else to do to make it run

Best regards...

Frank

Comment: openSUSE 11.3???? That's an 11 year old and 9 year out-of-date version?? However, I suspect your problem is due to the groups already existing. Use `groupadd -f "$grupo"` (and explain why `sudo` is not needed?) That said, your question is "How do I use `groupadd`?" which is better asked on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) You will likely get more responses on the correct StackExchange site.

Comment: (I recognize 11.3 as I have used SuSE/openSUSE since SuSE 7.0 -- along with Archlinux and Debian...)

Comment: The sudo is for testing, but the detail is when creating the groups, the groups are not created, the script tries to create them and gives me that error, and why does it work in Fedora?

I am running it in Suse not in OpenSuse.

Comment: See the "Before asking about problematic code" section of the [Stack Overflow 'bash' Info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).  In particular, *Check whether your script or data has DOS style end-of-line characters*.  Definitely check `/tmp/grupos_fles.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# El argumento tipo corresponde a usuario o grupo.
# El argumento accion corresponde a crear o eliminar cualquiera de los 
  anteriores.

tipo=$1
accion=$2
archivogrupo="/tmp/grupos.txt"
archivousuario="/tmp/usuarios_flex.txt"

if [ $tipo = "usuario" ]; then
    for linea in $(cat $archivousuario | tr " " _ | tr -d '\r')
    do
        nombre=`echo $linea|cut -d, -f1`
        usuario=`echo $linea|cut -d, -f2`
        grupo=`echo $linea|cut -d, -f3`

        if [ $accion = "crear" ]; then
            useradd $usuario -c $nombre -m -G $grupo
        else
            userdel $usuario -r -f
        fi
    done
        echo "----- Usuarios procesados ----"
    exit 0

elif [ $tipo = "grupo" ]; then
    for grupo in $(cat $archivogrupo)
    do
        if [ $accion = "crear" ]; then
            groupadd $grupo
        else
            groupdel $grupo
        fi
    done
    exit 0
    echo "----- Grupos procesados ----"
fi
```